# Certain UIActivityViewController services missing from my app

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have implemented `UIActivityViewController` within my app and can successfully share both strings and images. However, I notice that when you share an image within the iOS Photos app, there are some services that do not appear in my app. Namely Print, Use as Wallpaper, and Assign To Contact, and Photo Stream. My app is able to use Mail, Message, Facebook, Twitter, and Copy just fine.

I am thinking that either:

1.) These extra services have been implemented as custom services within the Photos app using `UIActivityItemProvider`, `UIActivityItemSource`, etc..

2.) The data that I am providing is not in the correct format to be used with these services.

I have read through the documentation a few times, but don't seem to see anything about it.

Edit: Showing code as requested:

```
#define SM_SHARE_IMAGE_AND_STRING 1

-(void)actionToolbarViewControllerUserTappedShareButton:(SMActionToolbarViewController*)sender{
    // Reposition anchor view for UIPopoverController to point at
    [self repositionAnchorViewToButtonFrame:self.actionToolbarViewController.shareButtonFrame];

    // Asynch download of image
    [SMUtility downloadAsset:self.selectedAsset completion:^(UIImage *image) {
        // Create image source
        SMActivitySource *activityImageSource = [[SMActivitySource alloc]initWithImage:image];
#if defined(SM_SHARE_IMAGE_AND_STRING)
        // Create string source
        NSString *assetsString = [SMUtility assetsString:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.selectedAsset]];
        SMActivitySource *activityStringSource = [[SMActivitySource alloc]initWithString:assetsString];

        // Present UIActiviyViewController within an UIPopoverController
        NSArray *items = [@[activityImageSource, activityStringSource]mutableCopy];
#else
        NSArray *items = [@[activityImageSource]mutableCopy];
#endif

        UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
        [activityViewController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){
            [SMMixPanel eventSharePhotoMethod:@"Share"];
        }];
        self.buttonPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityViewController];
        [self.buttonPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.anchorView.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Show the code you use to create your `UIActivityViewController`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The Print, and Assign To Contact activities are standard activities shown by the `UIActivityViewController` as long as you provide the proper data.
2. You must provide a `UIImage` for the Assign To Contact activity. See the docs for `UIActivityTypeAssignToContact`. See the docs for `UIActivityTypePrint` for details on what it accepts.

The "Use As Wallpaper" seems to be a custom activity shown only in the Photos app.

Comment: Thank you for that information. I am reading through the documentation for `UIActivityTypeAssignToContact`, `UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll`, and `UIActivityTypePrint` which all say that UIImage can be used. `UIActivityTypePrint` specifically says that it must be a local image, but the other two do not. 

I have modified my code (above) to use only UIImage. Testing it out by pressing Email, I see that it is indeed the image. However I do not get the service icons for neither Add to Contact nor Save To Camera Roll. Any clue to why? The documentation doesn't really say anything additional.

Comment: I have also modified +[SMUtility downloadAsset] to write the image to disk, then create a new UIImage from local storage, and then pass that UIImage to the block. Same results.

Comment: Without knowing how `SMActivitySource` is implemented, there is no way to know what the issue is. Why not pass an array containing a simple `UIImage` to the `initWithActivityItems:` method? Also, make sure all this UI code is being done on the main thread.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I was wrapping the UIImage with SMActivitySource, which of course isn't correct. I removed that step and it's working great.